# Ошибка Python IndexError: list index out of range что делать?

Tags: python, list, beautiful-soup, telebot, bs4

```
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup
import telebot
import time


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startmess(message):
    sendmessstart = f"Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!\n Введите команду rub чтобы узнать курс доллара в рубли"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, sendmessstart)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['rub'])
def send_text(message):
    DOLLAR_RUB = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85&oq=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j0l2j69i61l3.1190j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
    full_page = requests.get(DOLLAR_RUB, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
    convert=soup.findAll("span", {"class": "DFlfde", "class": "SwHCTb", "data-precision": 2})
    rub = (convert[0].text)
    chatid = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chatid, rub)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

> Ошибка Python IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо делать проверку длины (не пустоты) возвращаемого списка:

```
convert=soup.findAll(...
if len(convert) > 0:
    rub = (convert[0].text)
    chatid = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chatid, rub)
else:
    # Почему-то парсинг возвращает пустой список, но это уже другой вопрос
```